# R order() function -- appear to be a bug

Tags: r

Here is what I tried:

```
> order(c(-2, -3.4, -3.4, -3.4))

[1] 2 3 4 1
```

I wonder if you folks here can give a try as well... to see if this is a real bug

Comment: May be you could check : sort(c(-2, -3.4, -3.4, -3.4)) and
sort(c(-2, -3.4, -3.4, -3.4), decreasing=T)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no bug.  I think you're just misunderstanding what the function is doing. Read the help page for order and it will tell you that order returns a permutation that would put the vector in order.  So what this is telling you is that if you want to order the vector the 2nd item, then the 3rd item, then the fourth item, and finally the 1st item - that is the order you would put it in.  What that means is that if you reorder the vector according to what order gives you will end up with something that is sorted.

```
x <- c(-2, -3.4, -3.4, -3.4)
x[order(x)]
#[1] -3.4 -3.4 -3.4 -2.0
```

I have a feeling you want to look into the `rank` function.